# Javascript / Jquery Mobile - Select(1) onChange Reset Fields for Select(2)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I am a totally noob in JQuery Mobile programming and I would like to seek help...

I have two sets of Drop Down Lists and any Selection on the First Drop Down will reset the value in the Second Drop Down to the default value "Choose An Option".

Based on my current setup, nothing happens when you select any values in the 2nd drop down and then you try to reset with any values in the first drop down.

I have noticed that if I input data-role="none" in each of the Select Field in the two drop downs, it But will turn off the intended jquery mobile dropdown design and turn the field into a normal drop down and the function will work.

Can anybody advise me on how to keep the JQM design and still make the function work without having to input data-role="none"?

Thanks!

The Whole Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

    <title>
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Choose</h1>
        </div>


        <form id="boxes" name="boxes">
            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">

            </div>

        <div style="width: 60%; margin: 0px auto;">
              <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <select id="item1" name="Item1" onchange="message(this,'selecttwo');">
                <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select An Option</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
         </div>
            </div>





      <div id="target17" style="width: 60%; margin: 0px auto; display: block;">
              <div class="ui-field-contain">
            <select id="selecttwo" name="selecttwo">
                <option value="0">Choose An Option </option>
                <option value="1">ONE</option>
                <option value="2">TWO</option>
                <option value="3">THREE</option>
                <option value="4">FOUR</option>
                <option value="5">FIVE</option>
                <option value="6">SIX</option>
            </select>
         </div>
            </div>


        </form>
<script type = "text/javascript">       
function message(which,fld) {
    document.getElementById(fld).value = "0";
}
</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me without any issues. You must be having some error in function "boxes()" that's not letting it run the line :

```
 var s2 = document.getElementById('item2');
 s2.value="abc";
```

Comment: Hi ignVinayak, are there any ways to check for errors in that function?

Comment: I have found the root cause... There's a conflict with JQuery Mobile JS File and the native JS File. I apply data-role="none" to both the Select Fields and it works now! But now my interface looks ugly.